# AppInsights autocollection with ExpressJs

Tags: express, appinsights

I am try to implement telemetry collect with AppInsights on my ExpressJs server.

I have setup AppInsights like this :

```
appInsights.setup(appConfig.InstrumentationKey)
            .setAutoDependencyCorrelation(true)
            .setAutoCollectRequests(true)
            .setAutoCollectPerformance(true, true)
            .setAutoCollectExceptions(true)
            .setAutoCollectDependencies(true)
            .setAutoCollectConsole(true)
            .setUseDiskRetryCaching(true)
            .setSendLiveMetrics(false)
            .setDistributedTracingMode(appInsights.DistributedTracingModes.AI)
            .start();
```

In AppInsights portal, I don't see the log of API call.

I have see some examples ([here](https://dev.to/kenakamu/application-insights-sdk-for-node-js-part-2-2el) and [here](https://github.com/ZEISS/appinsights-express-middleware)) where they implement middleware.

Do I need to implement a middleware to collect events and logs ? Or Autocollect will do the job (with the correct settings) ?

Thanks in advance for you help.